# Cakephp 2.+ $this->Model->validates(); always return true

Tags: validation, cakephp, controller

i've search through stackoverflow. Most of the question resemble this problem,but it doesn't helped me. I've read the documentation of cakephp 2.0 and still can't find my answer.

My problem is: I've got seperate forms in a view. Each post has a different $this->request->data. Which what i wanted. I want each forms use a subset of validation of this model. But the problem is that they always 'return true'. Even when i've specified the fieldList.

View:

```
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Postcode');?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Postcodeletter');?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Submit');?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end();?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Password');?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('checkPassword');?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Submit');?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end();?>
```

Controller:

```
unset($this->request->data['User']['Id']);
$this->User->set($this->request->data);

if ($this->User->validates(array('fieldList' => array('Postcode')))) {

            //valid

            } else {
           //error
    }
```

Model:

```
    class User extends AppModel {

public function beforeSave($options = array()){
    if(isset($this->data['User']['Password'])){
        $this->data['User']['Password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['Password']);
    }
    return true;
}
public $primaryKey = 'Id';

public $validate = array(

   'Firstname' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'on' => 'create',
            'message' => '*Vult uw voornaam in' 
    ),
'Postcode' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => 'numeric',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'on' => 'create',
            'message' => 'Needs to be numbers'  
            ),
        'minLength' => array(
            'rule' => array('minLength',4),
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'on' => 'create',
            'message' => 'Min 4 numbers'
            )
          )

);// end $validate
```

}

Is there's something i've did wrong in the 'if-statement'?

Ps: I've shorten my codes, I think the problem is clear and i'm sorry for my poor english.

UPDATE :

added `$this->User->set($this->request->data);` 
added `unset($this->request->data['User']['Id'])` now it works.

Comment: what the database fields called?

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? validates() never works alone. It always needs the data passed to the model first.

Comment: @cornelb 
| Firstname | Postcode |  <-

Comment: @mark
I forgot to $this->User->set($this->request->data); , i've set this recently and still debugging. but i think it's something here.

Comment: You should show us the post data in $this->request->data and also what $this->User->validationErrors contains after the validates() call.

Comment: @mark 

i've founded the solution i will update this as soon as possible. $this->User->validationErrors <- gave me array(). empty array, so it's was hard for me to find out what it was.

But the problem was in the $this->request->data. Somehow this request also pass the $this->request->data['User']['Id']. The validation return somehow always true when you pass en the 'Id' with it.

Comment: Of course, because you made the mistake of using `'on' => 'create',`. That will essentially result in no validation rules here, thus the validation with no rules will return true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `'on' => 'create'` when it is not justified.
In your case it is not.

You would want to always validate the minLength or notEmpty, even on edit.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Debug-Level set to 2 in Core-Config? *(app/Config/core.php)*

Can you add the output of this in your Controller to your question?

```
// Put this before your If-Statement

debug( $this->User->invalidFields(); );

// You may copy the rendered output
```

I don't know about your Software, but what helps me often figuring out why cake's behaviour's such against my expectation is debugging my Code using a PHP-IDE and X-Debug for example.

Comment: The debug-level is '2'. and the debug( $this->User->invalidFields()); gave me 'array()', which no result.

Comment: And you submit Formdata that's definately invalid?

Comment: I think it's invalid. I want the postcode minimum 4 numbers. and i've just entered two numbers. Is the rule of my model maybe wrong?

Comment: You are at least missing one (closing) bracket ")" after "//end postcode" /- If you indent arrays correctly in your code, there is no need for comments after each bracket - then it'll be easy readable ;-)